# Reading ascii file to binary

Tags: binary, base64, ascii

I've created a file.txt with the string "7F" in it. I read it using apaches library:

```
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(new Base64InputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(fileName)));
```

And this is the array I get:

```
[-20]
```

which equates to 1110 1100 when i was expecting 1111 1111
I guess my question is how to encode a string in ascii which would generate the Byte 1111 1111?

Answer (score 1):

`1111 1111` binary = `255` decimal. According to [this](http://www.ascii-code.com/) ASCII chart, that would be the `ÿ` character.

Comment: why doesn't it work when i use this site? http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-binary-converter

Comment: That's a Windows-1252 chart not an ASCII chart. (ASCII is only the first part 0-127.) Windows-1252 is one of many character sets that are sometimes called ANSI or Extended ASCII. But, if you don't say Windows-1252, no one will know which you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the ASCII Character:'ÿ'

The following code should get you what you want:

```
Character s= 'ÿ';
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(s));
```

You can use an online utility like: 
https://www.branah.com/ascii-converter
to help you out.